# C# Asynchronous Tasks - MANDRILL API

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library, mandrill

I am setting up the Mandrill Api for our internal systems.

I can get the API working ok, and can receive the emails from it, the issue I have is when I try and get the result from the Send request, the system just hangs indefinitely.

My code is as below:

```
public async Task<bool> SendEmail(MandrillSendTemplateRequest request)
{
    var result = await _mandrill.SendMessageTemplate(Map(request));
    return result[0].Status.ToString() == "sent";
}
```

If I run the above code WITHOUT the return, then the email sends fine.
If I run the above code WITH the return, then the email sends fine, but my program just hangs.

Can anyone shed any light on this issue?

*Edit. For reference, I am using the Mandrill .Net Wrapper By Shawn Mclean from NuGet Packages. [Mandrill API 2.2.7](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mandrill/)*

*Edit. Button Click Event that calls the SendEmail method:*

```
  Private Sub btnTest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTest.Click

    Try
        WaitCursor = True

        Dim mgr As New CustomerCommunicationsManager()
        Dim r As New MandrillSendTemplateRequest()
        Dim m As New MandrillMessage()

        m.FromEmail = "from@icloud.com"
        m.FromName = "fromName"

        m.Subject = "Test"
        m.ForeName = "Software"
        m.Surname = "Dept"
        m.EmailAddress = "software@icloud.com"

        r.Message = m
        r.TemplateName = "WelcomeBasic"

        Dim sent As Boolean = mgr.Mandrill.SendEmail(r).Result

    Catch ex As Exception

    Finally
        WaitCursor = False
    End Try


End Sub
```

*Edit. Code for Map(request) (SendEmail Method)*

```
private SendMessageTemplateRequest Map(MandrillSendTemplateRequest obj)
{
    if (obj == null) { return null; }
    return new SendMessageTemplateRequest(Map(obj.Message), obj.TemplateName, Map(obj.TemplateContent));
}

private EmailMessage Map(MandrillMessage obj)
{
    if (obj == null) { return null; }

    return new EmailMessage
    {
        AutoHtml = obj.AutoHtml,
        AutoText = obj.AutoText,
        FromEmail = obj.FromEmail,
        FromName = obj.FromName,
        Important = obj.Important,
        PreserveRecipients = obj.PreserveRecipients,
        Subject = obj.Subject,
        Tags = obj.tags,
        To = new EmailAddress[] { new EmailAddress(obj.EmailAddress, obj.FullName) },
        TrackOpens = obj.TrackOpens,
        TrackClicks = obj.TrackClicks
    };
}

private IEnumerable<TemplateContent> Map(IEnumerable<MandrillTemplateContent> obj)
{
    if (obj == null) { return null; }

    List<TemplateContent> content = new List<TemplateContent>();

    foreach (MandrillTemplateContent c in obj)
    {
        content.Add(new TemplateContent{ Content = c.Content, Name = c.Name });
    }

    return content;
}
```

Comment: You need to also post how you are calling this method. Do you call `Wait` or `Result` on the returned task?

Comment: I just call as above, the _mandrill part is actually the reference to their API.

Comment: So how is `SendMail` called? What calls that?

Comment: At the moment, as I am just testing, it comes from a Windows Form Button Click Event

Comment: Either the indexer of `result`, the `Status` get accessor or the `ToString()` method is hanging. Have you debugged using step into? try putting breakpoints in the indexer/accessor/tostring

Comment: if I put a breakpoint on the return then the breakpoint doesn't get hit. if the breakpoint is on the trigger (var result = await...) then no error is seen.

Comment: Show the code that calls `SendEmail`

Comment: I have edited the original post. Please see above. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have a deadlock on your hands because you're **blocking on an asynchronous method in the context of the UI thread**. You shouldn't block on async code, you should await it:

```
Private Async Sub btnTest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTest.Click
...
        Dim sent As Boolean = Await mgr.Mandrill.SendEmail(r)
End Sub
```

The UI thread has a `SynchronizationContext` (you can see that `SynchronizationContext.Current != null`) that makes sure code after an await is posted to the single UI thread.

Since you're blocking the UI thread with `Task.Result` the code after the await can't run which means the task can't complete and so the UI thread will block forever.

You can mitigate that by telling the await not to capture the `SynchronizationContext` using `ConfigureAwait(false)` but while that's a good practice you shouldn't block to begin with:

```
public async Task<bool> SendEmailAsync(MandrillSendTemplateRequest request)
{
    var result = await _mandrill.SendMessageTemplate(Map(request)).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return result[0].Status.ToString() == "sent";
}
```

Comment: Hi  Thanks so much for your answer, I now have a build issue in that "Expression is of type 'Boolean', which is not awaitable."

Comment: @Richard.Gale It seems you're trying to await something that doesn't return a task. Are you sure you're calling an async method?

Comment: Yes, thats what i read online that all of the calls in this API are async

Comment: @Richard.Gale If the method doesn't return a task it's not part of the async-await pattern.

Comment: How would I know if it returns a task?

Comment: @Richard.Gale you can use Go To Declaration in Visual Studio

Comment: it returns Task<List<EmailResult>>